# Using default parameter values with Ninject 3.0

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-3

I have a class with a constructor having a parameter with a default value. With Ninject 2.2, it would honor the `[Optional]` attribute and work fine *with no binding defined* against a constructor declared like so:

```
public EmployeeValidator([Optional] IValidator<PersonName> personNameValidator = null)
```

Since upgrading to Ninject 3.0, construction of this object fails with a message stating that the provider returned null:

> Test method ValidatorIsolated.Tests.EmployeeValidatorTest.CreateEmployeeValidatorTest threw exception:
>
> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IValidator{PersonName} using conditional implicit self-binding of IValidator{PersonName}
>
> Provider returned null.
>
> Activation path:
>
> 2) Injection of dependency IValidator{PersonName} into parameter personNameValidator of constructor of type EmployeeValidator
>
> 1) Request for IValidator{Employee}
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that the provider handles creation requests properly.

Is the `[Optional]` attribute still honored when a default value for a parameter is present and what is the best way to handle injection with optional parameters such as this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Optional Attribute is ignored in this situation because there is always the default value available- But the provided value is null. Null is not an allowed value by default.

You can override this behavior by setting NinjectSettings.AllowNullInjection to true.

Comment: @The Davester: Smells like a pull request for an improvement to an error message :P

Comment: The `NinjectSettings.AllowNullInjection` is generally the `kernel.Settings' property for those assuming it's a static property.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid setting `AllowNullInjection` globally while still injecting a parameter only when a binding exists by configuring your binding like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<IEmployeeValidator>()
      .To<EmployeeValidator>()
      .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(IValidator<PersonName>), c => c.Kernel.TryGet<IValidator<PersonName>>());
```

`[Optional]` is not needed for that.